# Is there a website to search for packages across all popular package managers?

Tags: package-management

I remember coming across a website that allows me to search for packages across all popular package managers, but I can't find it.

Can anyone help me find the website? TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [pkgs.org](https://www.pkgs.org) Lists official and unofficial repos 21 distros and multiple version of some, deb and rpm universal.
2. [Distrowatch](https://distrowatch.com/dwres.php?resource=package-in-distro)  tracks some 200 packages of their tracked distros.
3. There is a Github Badge that uses a website to track latest version of various packages but I cannot find it now
   Edit: It's name is [Repology](https://repology.org/). Found on the answer it is duplicate of.

Note: I'm not afflicted with any of the websites.